# Is there an "ON CREATE" foreign key constraint?

Tags: sqlite

I am just getting started with SQLite and SQL in general. I am using a [PHP script to facilitate a secure login process](https://github.com/panique/php-login-one-file). This script uses an SQLite database with a table `users` containing user id (primary key) username, email and password hash. I want to store additional information on users (e.g. name), but I don't want to touch the table the script uses, so I'm trying to add another table `users_info` with a foreign key referencing the user id of the `users` table. This takes care of deleting a user from the `users_info` table whenever I delete a user from the login script's `users` table, but I also want a new row (with the correct user id) to be created in `users_info` whenever I register a new user to the `users` table.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like what you actually want is a trigger: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html
in your case something like `CREATE TRIGGER user_info_trigger AFTER INSERT ON user ...`

Comment: A foreign key constraint on the `user_info` table (on the column which references `user.id`) makes sense too. Make sure you enable foreign keys too (https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable)

Comment: Thank you, if you add this as an answer I'll accept it.